Translate Google BigQuery to Snowflake SQL
I'm translating a BigQuery below to Snowflake.
select event_date,user_pseudo_id,event_name, event_timestamp,
(SELECT COALESCE( value.string_value, CAST(value.int_value AS string), CAST(value.double_value AS string), CAST(value.float_value AS string) ) FROM UNNEST (event_params)   WHERE    KEY = 'key1' ) AS key1, 
(SELECT COALESCE( value.string_value, CAST(value.int_value AS string), CAST(value.double_value AS string), CAST(value.float_value AS string) ) FROM UNNEST (event_params)   WHERE    KEY = 'key2' ) AS key2 
FROM `bigquery.analytics.events_20240812`;

I expect the result as below. The way I'm doing in Snowflake is creating 2 separate tables for key1 and key2, then full join them together. However, I will have hundreds of keys in the future. It would difficult to accomplish the goal with hundreds of joins.
Thank you so much!
Below is what I got from BigQuery and would expect the same for Snowflake.


Hi - please don’t use images (as no one can copy your data). Provide data as editable text, formatted as tables. Please also update your question with the DDL for your table and the sample data that produces the result you’ve shown

If your events look like:
with events(event_date, user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp,event_params) as (
    select $1, $2, $3, parse_json($4) from values
    ('2024-08-12'::date, '111.11', 123456, '[
{"key":"key0", "float_value":-1.234},{"key":"key1", "string_value":"Prifilled"},{"key":"key2", "string_value":"[UUID]"}
]'),
    ('2024-08-12'::date, '111.11', 123456, '[
{"key":"key0", "float_value":4.567},{"key":"key1", "string_value":"Prifilled"},{"key":"key2", "string_value":"ot-group-id-COOO4"}
]')
)

which is too say, a row of values, and some JSON values, then FLATTEN is the most related to UNNEST command:
select
    e.event_date,
    e.user_pseudo_id,
    e.event_timestamp,
    f.value:key as k,
    COALESCE( f.value:string_value, f.value:int_value::text, f.value:double_value::text, f.value:float_value::text) as v,
    f.seq 
from events as e,
table(flatten(input=>e.event_params)) as f
where f.value:key in ('key1', 'key2')

gives:

which grouping via the SEQ and using MAX and IFF to pivot the values like:
select 
    event_date, 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    event_timestamp,
    min(iff(k='key1', v, null)) as key1,
    min(iff(k='key2', v, null)) as key2
from (
    select
        e.event_date,
        e.user_pseudo_id,
        e.event_timestamp,
        f.value:key as k,
        COALESCE( f.value:string_value, f.value:int_value::text, f.value:double_value::text, f.value:float_value::text) as v,
        f.seq 
    from events as e,
    table(flatten(input=>e.event_params)) as f
    where f.value:key in ('key1', 'key2')
)
group by 1,2,3,seq

gives:

which appears to match your impled data and desired result.

Thank you SO much Simeon! Inspired by your answer,  pivot() function also works.

nod, PIVOT is good, I like to roll my own, because I just do. But glad the answer helped you find something that works for you.



with cte as (
    select
        event_date,
        user_pseudo_id,
        event_timestamp,
        ep.value:key as event_key,
        a.seq,
        coalesce(
            ep.value:value:string_value,
            ep.value:value:int_value::string,
            ep.value:value:double_value::string,
            ep.value:value:float_value::string
        )::string as event_value
    from
        b_cmg_guoz_db.temp.events_json_all_sample a,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(input => event_params) ep
)
select
    *
from
    cte
    pivot(
        min(event_value) for event_key in (
            'key1',
            'key2'
        )
    )
; 




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
